# .NET Core How to check file not in use on network share

Tags: c#, file, .net-core, concurrency

Situation:

- a file share
- one app write files to it
- files are big and write process duration is long
- another one app copy this files for "processing"
- necessary to be sure a file already copied by first one app

I use File.Open approach, but it not work as expected. File in copy state can be freely copied/moved.

```
    public bool FileIsFreeToUse(Guid iterationGuid, FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                // log skipped

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // log skipped

            return false;
        }
    }
```

So, my questions.

1. Exists a way to check file in network share is not used with File.Open?
2. Is it file size check only possible way?
3. Best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried attempting an exclusive access by using [FileShare.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare) instead?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried. Did not help. Also, I think it is just parameter to "other" applications.